# Android fragment onCreateView creating duplicate views on top of each other

Tags: android, user-interface, view

In my app, when I suspend, upon resume, I get duplicate views stacked on top of each other, with the topmost being the only editable ones.  My onCreateView() is below.  Any suggestions?

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    Item currentItem = Global.DataManager.getItem();

    // Set the different details
    ((EditView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_title))
            .setText(currentItem.getTitle());
    ((EditView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_type))
            .setText(currentItem.getType());
    ((EditView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_details))
            .setText(currentItem.getDetails());

    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not in `onCreateView()`, most likely. Instead, I suspect that you are creating the fragment a second time. You only need to create a fragment once, even if activity is destroyed and recreated due to a configuration change (e.g., portrait -> landscape rotation).

Comment: You were absolutely right.  Sorry about the delay for accepting your answer, but your response seemed to be the cause of my issues.