# Fragment create/restore a duplicate view when re-attach

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragment

I have 6 pages in my `ViewPager` and `OffscreenPageLimit=2`(easy to reproduce my bug). 
all data in the 6 pages are from server. In `onCreateView`, I send a request to server, and refresh UI when I get data from server.

When I select first tab and change to last quickly several times, some pagers display wrong. And at that time my field `mMainLayout` in fragment is not null.

For example, I have a `ListView` in my first page. When the page is wrong, another *ListView* is on the top of the right *ListView*. When I try to scroll *ListView*, only the right one(bottom one) moved.

I know that my response listener holds reference of *mMainLayout* and some other views, I create a new *mMainLayout* in method *onCreateView*, I thought fragment use new *mMainLayout* when it re-attach/restore and drop the old one(or remove it from the container). But I was wrong.

I know that `FragmentPagerAdapter` attach/re-attach fragment in `instantiateItem` and detach in `destroyItem`. Adapter didn't remove a fragment. Adapter didn't make a new fragment. Fragment keep the view and view states itself.

I remove *mMainLayout* from container and set all views in my fragment null at `onDestroyView` and save nothing in `onSaveInstanceState`. But still easy to reproduce the bug.

activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("com.souyidai.intent.action.log_fragment"));
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    mResources = getResources();
    mMainPagerAdapter = new MainPagerAdapter(fragmentManager);
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPager.setAdapter(mMainPagerAdapter);
    mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(CACHE_SIZE);
    mIndicator = (TabPageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    mIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);
    ...
}

private class MainPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public MainPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        MainConfig.TabItem tab = mTabs.get(position);
        String tabType = tab.getTabType();
        String code = tab.getCode();
        MainConfig.TabItem.SubTabItem subTabItem = tab.getSubitem().get(0);
        Fragment fragment = MainFragment.newInstance(code, subTabItem);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        MainConfig.TabItem tab = mTabs.get(position);
        return tab.getTitle();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mTabs.size();
    }
}
```

fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mContainer = container;
    mMainLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    ...
}


@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    mContainer.removeView(mMainLayout);
    mContainer = null;
    mMainLayout = null;
    mSwipeRefreshLayout = null;
    mListView = null;
    mHeaderLayout = null;
    mFooterLayout = null;
    ...
}
```

android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    if (mCurTransaction == null) {
        mCurTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    }

    final long itemId = getItemId(position);

    // Do we already have this fragment?
    String name = makeFragmentName(container.getId(), itemId);
    Fragment fragment = mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(name);
    if (fragment != null) {
        if (DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, "Attaching item #" + itemId + ": f=" + fragment);
        mCurTransaction.attach(fragment);
    } else {
        fragment = getItem(position);
        if (DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, "Adding item #" + itemId + ": f=" + fragment);
        mCurTransaction.add(container.getId(), fragment,
                makeFragmentName(container.getId(), itemId));
    }
    if (fragment != mCurrentPrimaryItem) {
        FragmentCompat.setMenuVisibility(fragment, false);
        FragmentCompat.setUserVisibleHint(fragment, false);
    }

    return fragment;
}
```

I find this:

[Android fragment onCreateView creating duplicate views on top of each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037752/android-fragment-oncreateview-creating-duplicate-views-on-top-of-each-other)

But I only create new fragment in `FragmentPagerAdapter.getItem`. So we're different.

I solve this by removing all children of *mMainLayout* if *mMainLayout* is not null in method *onCreateView*. Then everything is fine. But I am still confused as to why this bug happens?

I did some tests.
1. try to add a fragment twice, app crash and log says: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added: ...
2. try to attach a fragment twice, system does not call `Fragment.onCreate` or `Fragment.onCreateView`

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: use 'setRetainInstance (true)' api of fragment If you want to retain your fragment state.
On loading same fragment 2nd time it will load UI component from previous instance if it is their in memory else new fragment will be created.
So you doesn't need to make all UI componet null in ondestroyview method.

Comment: @keyur9779 I don't want to retain my fragment states. but it looks like that fragment still restore state from previous.

Comment: @android_su create fragment with Tag and use findfragmentbytag method(method will return null if fragment not their in memory so put null check), it will give your privous fragment if it their in memory.

Comment: @keyur9779 FragmentPagerAdapter.instantiateItem set tag for my fragments and use findFragmentByTag to retrieve fragments.

Comment: I didn't get you, Please elaborate more on it.

Comment: @keyur9779 I post FragmentPagerAdapter code.

Comment: it seems to be correct. 

But let me know if you fail to achive target result.

Comment: Why are you override instantiateItem? You just need to override getItem(Along with  getCount()) in case of FragmentPagerAdapter or FragmentStatePagerAdapter, in order to return fragment at particular position from list of fragments.

Comment: @android_su I was facing same issue and resolved with trick of checking if baseview is null only then inflating it, else returning the existing layout instance. you can see my answer If it is helpful.

Answer (score 3):

This situation occurred due to custom implementation of `instantiateItem()`
One thing I have noticed. You are messing check if fragment is already added.

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    if (mCurTransaction == null) {
        mCurTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    }

    final long itemId = getItemId(position);

    // Do we already have this fragment?
    String name = makeFragmentName(container.getId(), itemId);
    Fragment fragment = mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(name);
    if (fragment != null) {
        if (DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, "Attaching item #" + itemId + ": f=" + fragment);
        //make sure you are not attaching already added fragment
        //try with comment and uncomment two lines below
        //if(!fragment.isAdded())
        //mCurTransaction.attach(fragment);
    } else {
        fragment = getItem(position);
        if (DEBUG) Log.v(TAG, "Adding item #" + itemId + ": f=" + fragment);
        mCurTransaction.add(container.getId(), fragment,
                makeFragmentName(container.getId(), itemId));
    }
    if (fragment != mCurrentPrimaryItem) {
        FragmentCompat.setMenuVisibility(fragment, false);
        FragmentCompat.setUserVisibleHint(fragment, false);
    }

    return fragment;
}
```

Don't know why you are creating class member field for `mMainLayout`

```
//try to go with default
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
```

recommend you to study [this](http://billynyh.github.io/blog/2014/03/02/fragment-state-pager-adapter/)

Comment: If I add a fragment twice, app crash and log says: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added: ...

Comment: You are right, there's no necessary to hold reference of mMainLayout. But I have to hold some view reference in order to update view when get data from server.

Comment: My app is not crash, so I think it's no help to call fragment.isAdded

Answer (score 2):

You can try with code, I was facing similar issue got resolved with bellow changes. In that case no need to make null all the references in `onDestroyView`. as in that caseyou need to always make null check before using these reference anywhere else in the code.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if(mMainLayout == null)
    {
      mMainLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,false);
...
    } 
    return mMainLayout;
}
```

When `mMainlayout` is not null, it mean that your fragment instance has already one instance of the `mMainLayout` and already added to  `ViewGroup container` no need to add it again. You are facing issue as you are adding same view again to same container.

Comment: I metioned at last in my question that I solved the problem same as you. I want to know that why the view/fragment is added twice.

Comment: As same layout was already added in your ViewGroup container, so we need make null check for not adding it twice.